# Python Numpy Truth Matrix for Condition

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I think there should be such a thing in `numpy` but couldn't find it.

I have a numpy 2d array, which is a rectangle, which contains integer values. For example:

```
[[1 1 0 1 1]
 [4 3 3 4 4]
 [3 2 2 2 2]
 [2 3 3 3 3]
 [3 2 0 1 3]]
```

I have a second numpy array, which is a 1d array, which contains integers, usually fewer than the first. For example:

```
[3, 3, 5, 6]
```

For each integer of the 2d array I want to check, whether it is in the 1d array. If it is in the 1d array, I want a value `True` or `1` to be written into another 2d array of the same size as the 2d array with the integers, otherwise `False` or `0`. In the example:

```
[[F F F F F]
 [F F T F F]
 [T F F F F]
 [F T T T T]
 [T F F F T]]
```

(where T stands for True and F stands for False)

How can I do this in `numpy`?

It would be nice to have a general way of doing this depending on an arbitrary condition.

I've found some code online, which does this only for one number, where you can use the equals method:

```
X_new = (neighbors == 3) | (X & (neighbors == 2))
```

But if I use the `in` operator, I just get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Which seems clear and `any` or `all` doesn't do what I want, since they only return a single truth value, as needed by the expression, which is why they're suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `in1d` as it will flatten your 2D array:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1, 0 ,1, 1],
                  [4, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                  [3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  [2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  [3, 2, 0, 1, 3]])
>>> b = [3, 3, 5, 6]
>>> np.in1d(a, b).reshape(a.shape)
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Ha! That's great. Thanks. I was already fiddling with the in1d function, but in the wrong way and I thought I couldn't use it because the documentation said it would check in a 2D array.